# how to redirect a range of link to home .htacess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

sury for my bad english.
i am redirect a new domain to my site & i need redirecd his links auto to my home.
if yo type:

```
www.newdomain.com/forum/index.php?323233
```

this redirecd to my site:

```
www.domain.com/forum/index.php?323233
```

but this link give 404 error.
i need redirect /forum & all this range of this folder like:

```
/forum/ddf/3434334
/forum/indexfdsfk
etc
```

redirect to my home www.domain.com
please help me

Answer (score 0):

I found this

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} ^mydomain.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

here

[Pag](http://www.kingnomar.com/111/redirect-to-www-htacces-redirect/)